# Ember.js trigger destroy view from controller

Tags: ember.js

is there a way to destroy a view in ember.js? I don't need to just hide it, I need it to be cleaned up so a new template can go in the same view after.

on the documentation it says if you do

```
App.nameView.destroy()
```

it should work but it doesn't also

```
view.remove()
```

that doesn't work either :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a reference to the **ACTUAL RUNNING INSTANCE** of the view you want to destroy... ie the actual instance, and **then** call destroy on that. Calling destroy on the view class won't work. If this isn't the correct answer, please provide a jsbin and I'll help more on that. (ie need more context)